# Upload image base 64 para o Firebase

Tags: angularjs, ionic, firebase

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer o upload de imagens em base64 para o firebase, mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro. Tentei seguir o tutorial do Firebase no site oficial e um encontrado aqui no próprio stack, mas continuo recebendo o mesmo erro.

> {code: "storage/invalid-format", message: "Firebase Storage: String
>   does not match format 'base64': Invalid character found",
>   serverResponse: null, name: "FirebaseError"}

```js
$scope.upload = function (dataUrl, name) {
var image = dataUrl;
  uploadTask = firebase.storage().ref('profileImg',  loggedUserSrvc.getUser().uid).child('profileImg').putString(image, 'base64', {contentType:'image/jpg'});

 uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, // or 'state_changed'
   function(snapshot) {
  // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done');
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
   console.log('Upload is paused');
   break;
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
   console.log('Upload is running');
   break;
  }
   }, function(error) {
  console.log(error);
 }, function() {
   // Upload completed successfully, now we can get the download URL
   var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
 });

}
```

```html
<div class="card">
 <button  ng-click="upload(croppedDataUrl, picFile.name)" class="button button-balanced button-block">
  Salvar
 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando a câmera pelo ionic, existe uma lista de preferências que você deve configurar antes (CameraOptions), aqui você encontra a documentação: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/index.html

Nessas preferências você deve colocar:

```
destinationType: DATA_URL
```

Após isso, a sua camera estará retornando a foto já em base64